# Can I create a repository of objects in a HashTable?

Tags: java, class, object, hashtable

Looking up HashTable on oracle, it is used to store key and values in this form

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers= new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
numbers.put("one", 1);
numbers.put("two", 2);
numbers.put("three", 3);
```

I was making a mini RPG for fun and made a simple Item class, attributes shown in the snippet below.

```
public class Item {
/* These are the attributes of the Item class
 * 
 */
private int id;
private int str;
private int dex;
private int intelligence;
private int armor;
private int price;
private int levelReq;
....
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to store a bunch of different **Objects** of type **Item** inside a **HashTable** or if I should make a new **Class** called **ItemList** and just instantiate a bunch of **Objects** there instead. Anyone can provide a simple example of storing objects in a **HashTable** it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can, yes, but I'd think a set (HashSet) or even just a list would be better.

Comment: Storing everything into one ArrayList or something like that?

Comment: A hash table is for storing pairs, and doing a look-up on one item, the key, to get the second item.  If all you have is the objects, then a list is better.  If you want to look-up Items by, for example, their ID though, that's when you'd probably want to use a hash table.  But it depends on your application.

Comment: @markspace Thanks for the speedy response, think I will go for a List of objects then